# How can I apply random intermittent effects using ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, visual-effects

I would like to create a short video approx 30s long made up of a part of an audio file and 2 or 3 still images that transition between each other and apply some occasional glitch like effects.

```
ffmpeg-2  -loop 1 -i image1.jpeg \
                     -loop 1 -i image2.jpeg \
                     -loop 1 -i image3.jpeg \
                     -filter_complex "[0:v]xfade=transition=hrslice:duration=10:offset=30[v1]; [v1][2:v]xfade=transition=hrslice:duration=20:offset=40[v2]; [v2]chromashift=cbh='if(gt(random(0), 0.8), 1, 20)'[v]" \
                     -i Razbibriga.wav -c:v libx264 -map "[v]"  -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ss 30 -to 60 -movflags +faststart out.flv
```

I've managed to create a 30s clip with 3 images transitioning and taking the 30s->60s from the audio file.

I've tried to use the if() command to apply the chromashift only occasionally but it's being applied all the time.

I got the inspiration for using if from this command

`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb32 -s 1920x1080 -i /dev/zero -r 30 -filter_complex "movie='square.png'[sqr];[0:][sqr]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[canvas];[canvas]chromakey=0x008000:blend=0:similarity=0.15[canvas2];[0:][canvas2]overlay[canvas3];movie='input.mp4',scale=1920:1080[i1];[0:][i1]overlay='if(gt(random(0), 0.2), 1, 4)':'if(gt(random(0), 0.1), 1, 2)',colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131[i2];[i2][canvas3]overlay[mix1];movie='9v9VVN1RE84.mp4',scale=1920:1080[grit_i1];[grit_i1]chromakey=0x16FF0A:blend=0.2:similarity=0.3,colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3[grit1];[0:][mix1]overlay[o1];[o1][grit1]overlay[o]" -map "[o]" -c:v libx264 -crf 31 -frames:v 300 output.mp4`

which came from tutorial here: https://www.gariany.com/2020/08/ffmpeg-step-by-step-retro-video-filter

I don't yet fully understand how the pipeline works or when/how often the if() is being evaluated. In the example, using overlay I am guessing it's being evaluated on every frame. In my case, it seems like it's only being evaluated once.

Is this because I'm using still images? there a trick to make it evaluate each frame?

Thanks!